# regex march the first occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: regex, pcre

Given this string:

```
domain.com/?services&dsadasdhk&hdahjkda&fdsfsdfdsd
```

Using PCRE regex how can i match the first occurence of amp(&) sign ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
/&/
```

nothing special with that.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?328n5)

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to *capture* that ampersand.

```
^[^&]*(&)
```

If you only want to match without capture , you can use negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!.*&.*)&
```

Comment: This matches everything form beginig to the amp char, i just need the first amp char to be captured